# Is there a way to hide my referrer site on Google Analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics

Is there a way to hide my referrer site on Google Analytics

Example:

Referrer site is: referrer.com

```
<a href="example.com">CLICK HERE</a>
```

I do not want to appear referrer.com on Google Analytics of example.com

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to another place that you own, on a different domain.
Redirect from there to Example.com/wherever.
Your referrer is now the second site.

ie:

```
<a href="my-second-site.php?redir=%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftarget%3Fid%3D123">Example.com</a>
```

You go to the second domain, you send the encoded URL for example.com as a GET parameter to site2.
Then you set a redirect for the URL in the GET request.

...so if you own:
Dirty-Porn-Site.com

and

Puppies-Are-Cute.com

and you don't want your first site to show up as the referrer, you'd link to puppies-are-cute, with the URL you *actually* want to go to as a GET parameter...
...and then redirect from there to the real target.

There isn't a whole lot else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTTPS on referrer.com. HTTPS never passes referrer.